Javascript move event (mousemove, pointermove, touchmove) unprecise
I'm attempting to create a whiteboard in JavaScript. I'm using this code:
let lastTimestamp = 0;
const fps = 1000/60;
document.addEventListener("pointermove", moveMouse, false);
function moveMouse (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const now = performance.now();
    if (now - lastTimestamp >= fps) {
        lastTimestamp = now;
        if (current_stroke != null) {
            current_stroke.addPoint(e.x, e.y, e.pressure);
            if (e.pressure == 0) mouseUp();
        }
    }
}

It works great, until you start writing something or doing something more complex. For example, it always struggles with hard angles or drawing up, for some reason. It's not that it doesn't have enough resolution of strokes, you can draw really detailed curves, but somehow hard angles just confuse it.
Hard angles image
It is also a huge problem when drawing text, it works fine until it stops firing the event for some milliseconds, enough to make the text okay on some parts and blocky on others.
Stops firing the event image
Using mouse, stylus or touch doesn't change the outcome, and nor does change browser.
Does anyone know how to fix it or a better approach to creating this?
Thank you.

Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

you may try separating the event handler and the logic doing the actual drawing in a way so that the event handler will only sets the point itself in a global variable each time the event occurs and then on an another side a call to requestAnimationFrame(draw); where draw is your function using that point for rendering (and setting its value back to null... waiting for the event to reset it again). requestAnimationFrame

@CBroe The whole project is really minimal, it's only a test. https://codepen.io/noelX66/pen/abxqVGK

if (x - lastPoint[0] > spacing || y - lastPoint[1] > spacing) probably check the absolute value of those, if (Math.abs(x - lastPoint[0]) > spacing ...

Also note that pointerevents are already throttled to monitor frame rate.

The answer was James' comment. There was a condition that checked spacing between points of the strokes.
if (x - lastPoint[0] > spacing || y - lastPoint[1] > spacing) {
// Add point

The problem is that obviously this had to be the absolute value to get the distance. This was causing problems when the stroke was going up because it was getting negative values and therefore didn't meet the condition.
if (Math.abs(x - lastPoint[0]) > spacing || Math.abs(y - lastPoint[1]) > spacing) {
// Add point

This is something that I had never looked at because when debugging this, I had added a console.log on the pointermove, and I could see that it didn't print during the times when it was getting blocky strokes. In any case, thank you all.
